# How to extend interface nested object? (MUI theme use case)

Tags: typescript, inheritance, material-ui

I've created a MUI custom theme, and I want to add an additional color to the palette.

The initial custom theme looks as follows:

```js
import { ThemeOptions } from "@mui/material/styles";

export const themeOptions: ThemeOptions = {
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: colors.primary,
    },
    secondary: {
      main: colors.secondary,
    },
    background: {
      default: colors.bg,
      paper: colors.bg,
    },
  },
};
```

Then, when I add the new color "muted" to the palette, I need to include it in the type.

To do so I created a `CustomThemeOptions` interface. But I'm not able to make it work.

This is my current attempt:

```js
import { ThemeOptions } from "@mui/material/styles";

interface CustomThemeOptions extends ThemeOptions {
  palette: {
    muted: {
      main: string
    }
  }
}

export const themeOptions: CustomThemeOptions = {
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: colors.primary,
    },
    secondary: {
      main: colors.secondary,
    },
    background: {
      default: colors.bg,
      paper: colors.bg,
    },
    muted: {
      main: colors.muted,
    }
  },
};
```

However, the extension of the interface overrides the original palette definition and the `primary`, `secondary` fields are no longer accepted.

Comment: You are extending ThemeOptions, not the palette inside of it. When you redeclare palette, you are overwriting it. And why you need to add a new type to introduce a new color? Palette is already a generic record: `palette?: Record<string, any>`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to extend as well nested fields:

```
interface CustomThemeOptions extends ThemeOptions {
  palette: ThemeOptions["palette"] & {
    muted: {
      main: string
    }
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgFQBYFMToPJhsCAOwGc4BfOAMyghDgCIABEAV2AHoQBDGdKYLgBt2xGAE9B6YvQDcAKDnBCvKJS4BjdHADCLUbTSYceAiTjoAHr0IATUoay58RUgjlwPcMEPQxeALhQMRxMXAG16b0k-dHoAXTgAMkR3TzTWXhtAtzTcz24lQNF+QgBzVLyyCvI5KrkbdHVBLigtdRd4dsFoYkCuQjF5OUtIWDh2kngYYONnEkDdfRAHWdNSAF4UtKjfAK28r35uKDFs6oO4AsJArp6AOjAjlrEAGnPPMjeL4kaiG2ezhd0lxCuMIN0oMQ7j8Jv8Tl8Dp93h4AEYaADWpRoLFsgKBHgaahYghgN3B9xRpQR+O8YD4ZIhUMp1NySIuGXQWX2+KuDPuHJsLLSVWFbzI8iAA)